# Google Chrome shows gray circle cursor

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome shows a gray circle cursor when dev tools is active. Why is this happening and how do I make this stop?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Nov 29th, 2017 Update:**

Quick Update brought to you by [@Howdy_McGee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800452/howdy-mcgee).

*Chrome 62 you have to Add Device Type, there's no longer an option for Show Device Type.*

**Why is this happening?**

As Randy Hall points out below "This cursor indicates a "touch", such as your finger, for emulating touch events in (the) Chrome browser."

**July 20th, 2017 Update:** (version 59.0.3071.115) Just checking in again, looks like the below is still valid even through a bunch of Chrome updates.  They have changed the wording of `Show device type` to `Add device type`.  I've changed the wording below, but the image does not reflect the change.

They have also changed the way the `device type` settings work, explained below.

Once in responsive mode (via `F12`, then `ctrl + shift + m`) you will need to select the settings section indicated by the 3 grey circles, then select `Add device type`. Once you do this, a new drop down will appear next to the dimensions area, select `Mobile (no touch)`.  I imagine they did this so that you don't have to keep it on desktop and adjust the `user agent type` to a mobile device as I've described below.

[image]

**What do the Device Types mean?**

As of today (July 20th, 2017), the same settings for `device type` exist (as shown in the image above), but they work a bit differently than previously before:

- **Mobile:** Now scales the content on the page when resizing the window (to accurately simulate pixel density on a mobile device).  The circle that replaces your mouse, simulates a screen touch action when clicking (full fledged mobile development / testing).
- **Mobile (no touch):** Also scales the content on the page when resizing the window, but continues to use your regular mouse cursor for your click actions.
- **Desktop:** Does not scale content, uses regular mouse cursor (full fledged desktop development / testing).
- **Desktop (touch):** Also does not scale content, but replaces your regular mouse cursor with a circle that will simulate screen touches on click.

**But I still want to emulate a specific mobile device...**

There is still a way to override the user-agent with this `Mobile (no touch)` setting set.  When you're looking at your console (brought up via `F12`), you'll see the 3 vertical circles there next to the `console` tab, click them and bring up **Network Conditions**.  Within this section you'll see that `User agent` is set to `Select Automatically`, just turn this off and use the drop-down to change to the user-agent you want to emulate as.  This will allow you to emulate as a specific mobile device.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic solution. Thanks.

Comment: I get my mouse back, but the emulation goes back to the desktop version.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how to override the user-agent if you still want to emulate in a mobile environment (with your mouse and not the light gray circle).

Comment: Accepted this as the correct answer, since Chrome has changed.

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason, when I was viewing in responsive mode in the debugger, I got neither a cursor OR the gray circle. My cursor completely disappeared from the screen as soon as it would enter the site I was debugging. Setting the user-agent to "Mobile (no touch)" got me a cursor again. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer since in chrome 50, the steps have changed a bit.

Comment: WOW - those 2017 dots are *really* over there.  Missed them entirely.

Comment: Chrome 62 you have to Add Device Type, there's no longer an option for Show Device Type

Comment: As of today (06.10.2022), you need to click the 3 'dots', select 'more tools' -> 'Network conditions'.

Answer (score 27):

This cursor indicates a "touch", such as your finger, for emulating touch events in Chrome browser.

In the dev tools window, click the settings (gear) button in the bottom right. Go to the `Overrides` tab and disable `Emulate touch events`.

I'm posting this here because it took me a LONG while to find it via searches, and I know others have been having the same issue.

**Update** via Paulo Manuel Santos' comment:

From Chrome 32 the Emulation is configured in a different place. This is how I get to it: Elements, press Esc, Emulation, Sensors, Emulate touch screen

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Since Chrome 30 you will also see a notice listing all active overrides.

Comment: From Chrome 32 the Emulation is configured in a different place. This is how I get to it: Elements, press Esc, Emulation, Sensors, Emulate touch screen

Comment: In Chrome 49, when running in a mobile device mode, the option is no longer available.

Comment: @opznhaarlems, I came here to say the same thing.  They've removed it.  There is no longer an emulation tab, and it's not listed within the Senors tab.  I'm also using Chrome 49.  However, I did find a solution which I'll post as an answer.

Comment: I hope you're all happy I loved this feature. Now how am i supposed to see where the mouse is?

Comment: @AlexKrupka, there is still a way!  Check out the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 11):

At july 2017 this option calls **Add device type**:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: You sir, are are genius

Comment: Thank you! Irritation relieved.

Answer (score 6):

On Chrome 50 it seems the Emulation option is not available..
My workaround was to add a custom device with the 'Mobile (no touch)' option..

Answer (score 4):

[image: Click this icon to switch between mobile/desktop version]

When you click this ICON to activate (change to blue); The Grey Circle CURSOR will appear as representing finger touch for devices, and Deactivating this will simulate desktop version and Showing POINTER Cursor.

Comment: is there any way to hide it but still keeping its function? I'd like to record the screen of a website and use it for a mockup but I don't want the grey circle to appear

Comment: Not a good solution if you actually need the device toolbar open!

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me... So after clicking the aforementioned 3 dots in the bottom right corner, I selected **Settings** and then **Restore defaults and reload**

It's not a clean solution, but I had just to choose a new dock side position and then I was back to work

Comment: Actually, this is an EXCELLENT suggestion.  To "reset everything" (*INCLUDING* "reset touch emulation") then do *EXACTLY* this: Dev Tools > Settings > scroll to bottom > press [Restore defaults and reload] button.

Comment: The answer above didn't work for me either. I'm guessing because Chrome is on version 73 now and the answer above mentioned version 62. This solution seems faster and easier anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just deselect the Toggle device toolbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lcFl.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not good if you actually need the device toolbar open!