# Why is my div draggable on a smaller screen, but when I inspect it on a larger screen I'm no longer able to drag it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

Also, the position of the div changes when I inspect it on a larger screen as well. If I inspect how it looks on a larger screen, the position of the div totally changes.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/annahisenberg/ft10ersb/20/

to see full screen: https://jsfiddle.net/annahisenberg/ft10ersb/20/show

Code:

```js
class Drag extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: this.props.x,
      y: this.props.y,
      showMoreOptionsPopup: false,
      showHelpModal: false
    };

    this.reff = React.createRef();

    this.dragMouseDown = this.dragMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.elementDrag = this.elementDrag.bind(this);
    this.closeDragElement = this.closeDragElement.bind(this);
    this.showMoreOptionsPopup = this.showMoreOptionsPopup.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.pos1 = 0;
    this.pos2 = 0;
    this.pos3 = 0;
    this.pos4 = 0;
  }

  dragMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.pos3 = e.clientX;
    this.pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = this.closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = this.elementDrag;
  };

  elementDrag(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.pos1 = this.pos3 - e.clientX;
    this.pos2 = this.pos4 - e.clientY;
    this.pos3 = e.clientX;
    this.pos4 = e.clientY;
    this.setState({
      y: this.reff.current.offsetTop - this.pos2 + "px",
      x: this.reff.current.offsetLeft - this.pos1 + "px"
    });
  };

  closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  };

  showMoreOptionsPopup() {
    this.setState({
      showMoreOptionsPopup: !this.state.showMoreOptionsPopup
    });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <a
            id="more_options_button"
             className={this.state.showMoreOptionsPopup ? 'open' : null}
             onClick={this.showMoreOptionsPopup}
             style={{ left: this.state.x, top: this.state.y }}
             onMouseDown={this.dragMouseDown}
             ref={this.reff}
          >
            <div>
              <p>menu</p>
            </div>
          </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, The only problem i ran into is that i don't see anything on screen until i remove `left: 95rem;top: 39rem;`

Comment: @ZohirSalak did you look at it full screen with this link? https://jsfiddle.net/annahisenberg/ft10ersb/20/show

Comment: Yes i have, i didn't try it as a mobile device, the problem is react isn't recognizing the `onMouseDown` event so it doesn't event trigger on a mobile device [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525228/react-click-events-not-firing-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least within your fiddle, you set the initial position to

```
position: fixed;
left: 95rem;
top: 39rem;
```

which results in a fixed postion (probably out of view on small screens)

When you drag and drop this item, you are updating these values.

On page resize, the values stay the same, in terms of distance from left and distance from top. (rem has no relation to viewport- / screen-width or -height)

Regarding other positioning issues:
If you could tell what your wanted behavior is, then you might get closer to what you are looking for. You could try to set and update `right` instead of left, like here https://jsfiddle.net/61z7wkus/1/

Drag and Drop works, but only with mouse events because onmousedown doesn't handle touch events.

> fyi: The equivalent for onmousedown on touchscreen devices is ontouchstart,
>   and the equivalent of onmouseup is ontouchend. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

Perhaps you are within a device inspector with touch events?
Did you follow @moosa-saadat 's advice, disabling touch within the inspector?

> You probably have touch enabled in your chrome dev-tools. I disabled touch on my side and your code worked perfectly. To see how you can turn off touch in your dev-tools, refer to this question

Don't forget to check browser compatibility!
(That's why there is such a thing like [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about))

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning your div with `left: 95rem, top: 39rem`. On a smaller screen, this puts the element out of the viewport. Try using a percentage or [viewport units](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/) instead.

```
#more_options_button {
    left: 95vw;
    top: 39vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much fixes my positioning problem on different screen sizes, but it still doesn't fix my problem where I am not able to drag it when I inspect it on a larger screen. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change positioning as mentioned by [@Joshua-Minkler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11086793/joshua-minkler)
2. For the following problem:

> it still doesn't fix my problem where I am not able to drag it when I inspect it on a larger screen

You probably have touch enabled in your chrome dev-tools. I disabled touch on my side and your code worked perfectly. To see how you can turn off touch in your dev-tools, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842984/google-chrome-shows-gray-circle-cursor)

Comment: How do you turn off touch on mobile devices ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak the question is about large screens which are not mobile phones. And, this code works only for **mouse events**. So, if touch compatibility is required, then **touch events** need to be handled as well.