# why can't I select in inspect

Tags: web-scraping, developer-tools, web-inspector

I'm trying to set up a web scraper in Chrome using webscraper.io extension.

When I'm in inspect mode (developer tools), instead of getting an arrow or index finger, my browser shows me a vague grey dot for my cursor (screen shot below) and I can't select a link or text to scrape.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jci6m.png)

Comment: You setup your Chrome for mobile view. Check the following button: https://imgur.com/pyPYqBy.png - the one with a phone/tablet. If't it's light blue, click on it to deactivate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842984/google-chrome-shows-gray-circle-cursor Answer is here